# Where can I find a Transportation Specialist?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I am playing the mission "Traitor's caravan" in Metal Gear Solid 5. My problem is I cannot extract the caravan because I didn't find a specialist for that and I am stuck there. Where can I find the specialist required to develop the Fulton upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

The Transportation Specialist is found in mission 10, it's one of the prisoners being held in Lamar Khaate Palace. Alternatively, you can manually drive the truck out of the mission area, and it will count as having extracted it.

Comment: And without needing a guide, you can learn which mission has the Transportation Specialist just by looking at the mission select screen while mission 10 is selected. Each mission lists its available blueprints and skills above the map on the right. The grayed-out blueprints and skills are ones you already have.